# What does the regex parameter in .replace() function mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to replace a few unwanted strings that got scraped from a website. So I tried removing them using this code:

```
df["col_1"].replace('ï»¿', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

What exactly do `regex = True` and `inplace = True` mean?

Comment: Did you read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?

Answer (score 0):

When `inplace=True` is passed, the data is renamed in place (it returns nothing), so you'd use:

`df.some_column.operation(by=['some_col'], inplace=True)`

When `inplace=False` is passed (this is the default value, so isn't necessary), performs the operation and returns a copy of the object, so you'd use:

`df = df.some_column.operation(by=['some_col'])`

So by default dataframes are immutable, inplace make them mutable.

And `regex=True` makes the replacing string be a regular expression